# IOS drawing App, change buttoncolor

Tags: ios

i made a simple drawing App, with a toolpanel which contains a pencil, a paint brush and an eraser. There a 12 different colors to draw with.

Now, i would like the pencil and the paint brush image, change in the color of the active color from the colorpanel. How do I do that?

Something like;

When toolbutton:pencil is pressed, color pencil (image) is color:changecolor.

How to translate this in code?

This is my code for the buttons.

```
- (IBAction)colorChange:(id)sender
{

  UIButton *PressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;


switch (PressedButton.tag) {
    case 0:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(32, 152, 188);

        break;

    case 1:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(33, 114, 177);

        break;

    case 2:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(65, 79, 155);

        break;

    case 3:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(110, 58, 141);

        break;

    case 4:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(195, 26, 126);
                   break;

    case 5:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(228, 36, 40);

        break;

    case 6:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(234, 98, 36);

        break;

    case 7:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(241, 141, 33);

        break;

    case 8:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(252, 199, 19);

        break;

    case 9:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(255, 240, 79);

        break;

    case 10:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(139, 188, 63);
                   break;

    case 11:
        self.drawingView.lineColor = RGB(0, 144, 92);

        break;

  }

}

- (IBAction)toolChange:(id)sender
{
UIButton *toolButton = (UIButton*)sender;


switch (toolButton.tag){
    case 0:
        self.drawingView.drawTool = ToolTypePen;
        self.drawingView.lineWidth = 7;
        self.drawingView.lineAlpha = 1.0;
        self.potlood02.hidden=NO;
        self.kwast02.hidden=YES;
        self.gum02.hidden=YES;
        break;

    case 1:
        self.drawingView.drawTool = ToolTypePen;
        self.drawingView.lineWidth = 20;
        self.drawingView.lineAlpha = 0.67;
        self.potlood02.hidden=YES;
        self.kwast02.hidden=NO;
        self.gum02.hidden=YES;
        break;

    case 6:
        self.drawingView.drawTool = ToolTypeEraser;
        self.drawingView.lineWidth = 20;
        self.potlood02.hidden=YES;
        self.kwast02.hidden=YES;
        self.gum02.hidden=NO;
        break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you asking how to do this: `[btn setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>]` ?

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain your scenario properly. Not able to get your point.

Comment: So you have a template image for the pencil and paint brush, and you need to set the colour of the image when you draw it into your view context as the tools are moved over the screen?

Comment: So, i have an image for the pencilButton and i have a color palet. When a user clicks on a color, i want the pencil change into the same color. So, not only the background, but the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of your pencil image you could do something like this

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PencilImage.png"]; 
UIImage *newImage = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]; // your pencil image size
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];  // or whatever color that has been selected
imageView.image = newImage;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @melissa, was the answer above of any use to you? Let me know if more explanation needed.